# Redirect vs RedirectToAction in Asp.netCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am struggling to understand why the code below won't work

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    if (_signInManager.SignOutAsync().IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    { 
        return Redirect("/Account/Login");
    }
    return View();
}
```

but the code below works:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    if (_signInManager.SignOutAsync().IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    { 
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
    return View();
}
```

It seems as though the logout method never completes when I use the redirect method. Isn't Redirect and RedirectToAction methods essentially doing the same thing?

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? Didn't you forget to prepend a slash (/) to the url?

Comment: Try return `Redirect("~/Account/Login");`

Comment: you should store the result of `_signInManager.SignOutAsync();` then use that within the `if`

Comment: They are ultimately the same, but that assumes that `/Account/Login` actually resolves to `AccountController.Login`. If it's "not working", that's probably not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect will redirect to a URL and requires that you provide the full URL

RedirectToAction let's you redirect to a action in a controller by passing it the action and controller names.

If you want to redirect to a website like www.youtube.com you need to use Redirect.

In your example it could be not working because your Redirect should look like this

`return Redirect("~/Account/Login");`